# Airflow: from connexion.decorators.validation import RequestBodyValidator ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion.decorators.validation'

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-taskflow, airflow-api

After installing Airflow in Aws or Azure Vm whenever I'm entering the command "Airflow standalone" it ends up with an error below. I have tried it in different instances of EC2 and Azure Vm as well and also tried pip install connexion but I always get same error . Can anyone will help me with this

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/www/extensions/init_views.py", line 27, in 
from connexion.decorators.validation import RequestBodyValidator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion.decorators.validation'.

I tried Airflow Standalone command I was expecting it to run Aiflow.

Answer (score 3):

try to force it `pip install connexion==2.14.2`